# Building OData v3 date query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have a node in a controller which have to return a list of contacts created in the last fourteen days. I have been asked to use an OData query for this. The model of Contact have a property `CreatedOn`, which gives you the date when the contact was created and I use `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)`. The OData query I have come up with is

`"api/Contact?$filter=CreatedOn ge " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("s") + ".000Z"`

but is working partially, meaning I get the date when the last fourteen days start according to today's date, but it's not returning the contacts, instead is giving me an error

`"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: Syntax error at position 20 in "CreatedOn ge 2020-06-04T07:47:42.000Z`

which is weird because that position is not badly formed, I think. So if anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually received helped and got the answer before checking it here so I am going to post it. It is kind of similar to @Michael answer, in the sense that I had to use `Datetime` before doing the operation that is going to get when the last fourteen days start.
It turned out like this:

`$filter=CreatedOn ge DateTime'" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("s") + "'"`

Very grateful that Mike took his time to answer my question and I am terribly sorry for not respond sooner.

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax, note there are no spaces or parentheses between `datetime` and the value

```
$filter=CreatedOn ge datetime'2020-06-04T07:47:42.000Z'
```

greetings,

Mike